# Why am I getting this hgetall type error?

Tags: redis, node-redis

Here is the code in question:

```
let key = "player:"+player_id;
console.log(key);
console.log(typeof(key));

redisClient.hgetall(key, function (err, result) {

if (err) { 
console.log(err);
res.end(false);
}

console.log("this is the reply");
console.log(result);
res.end(result);
});
```

And here is the console.log output and error:

```
player:5db138fdc0
string
this is the reply
{ name: 'Noah' }
_http_outgoing.js:739
      throw new TypeError('First argument must be a string or Buffer');
      ^

TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:739:13)
    at Command.callback (/home/noah/http_service/index.js:228:21)
    at normal_reply (/home/noah/http_service/node_modules/redis/index.js:726:21)
    at RedisClient.return_reply (/home/noah/http_service/node_modules/redis/index.js:824:9)
    at JavascriptRedisParser.returnReply (/home/noah/http_service/node_modules/redis/index.js:192:18)
    at JavascriptRedisParser.execute (/home/noah/http_service/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:574:12)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/noah/http_service/node_modules/redis/index.js:274:27)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
```

The typeof call is showing that it is a string, so I'm really scratching my head as to what my next steps should be.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the result was not in string format. So, I used JSON.stringify() in the res.end(). I should have been using the typeof() call on the result and not the key.